# Cycle Though Each Node in Variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a variable that contains several HTML nodes that have the same classes. I would like to cycle through each of them, and am wondering how I would do it.

I have tried the following, but nothing happened (console did not print out anything).

```
var myVar = "<div class='item'>Item01</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item02</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item03</div>";

$(myVar).find('.item').each( function() {
    console.log( $(this) ); //console does not output anything
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(myVar).find('.item')` will not contain anything.

What you need to do is:

```
$(myVar).has('.item').each(...)
```

Or just:

```
$(myVar).each(...)
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I meant to use the single quotes around each class name. I just wrote the code, and didn't copy + paste from my original as the original is much more complex.

Comment: The reasoning for me to use `$(myVar).find('.item')` was to find each `.item` in myVar, and then apply the `each()` function to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors in your code, also using `find` is redundant.

```
var myVar = "<div class='item'>Item01</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item02</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item03</div>";

$(myVar).each(function() {
    console.log($(this))
});
```